# OOP: When should I declare class members dynamically?

Tags: c++, oop

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class MyClass1
{
public:
    MyClass1(int a, int b, int c, int d) :data1(a), data2(b), data3(c), data4(d) {}
    ~MyClass1() = default;
private:
    int data1;
    int data2;
    int data3;
    int data4;
};

class MyClass2
{
public:
    MyClass2(int a, int b, int c, int d) :data1(a), data2(new int(b)), data3(make_shared<int>(c)), data4(make_unique<int>(d)) {}
    ~MyClass2() { delete data2; }
private:
    int data1;
    int* data2;
    shared_ptr<int> data3;
    unique_ptr<int> data4;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass1 mc1automatic(1, 2, 3, 4); // Case 1 : Every integer allocated on stack
    MyClass2 mc2automatic(1, 2, 3, 4); // Case 2 : Every integer except data1 allocated on heap
    unique_ptr<MyClass1> mc1dynamic = make_unique<MyClass1>(1, 2, 3, 4); // Case 3 : Every integer allocated on heap
    unique_ptr<MyClass2> mc2dynamic = make_unique<MyClass2>(1, 2, 3, 4); // Case 4 : Every integer allocated on heap
    return 0;
}
```

In this example, object that both mc1dynamic and mc2dynamic are pointing to, allocates their class member (Every data in MyClass1, and data1 in MyClass2) dynamically despite blueprint declaring them as automatic variables.

If I know for sure that the object (MyClass1, MyClass2 in this case) will be allocated dynamically, why would I ever choose to declare class members dynamically like I did in MyClass2?

Comment: Depends on your design. Primarily opinion based question.

Comment: In a kind of sick and twisted manner you might gain a semantic of having a locked-down type with the dynamic version while also having the automatic type with the other...this would be a design issue that you would resolve in a very intentional manner based on the absolute need to do so.  The answer is that it would happen because your design needs/requirements demanded that you do it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When should I declare class members dynamically?

Members cannot be "declared" dynamically. I suppose that you mean to ask when to allocate dynamically.

Here are a few cases where you would want to allocate dynamically:

- The lifetime of the sub object isn't directly tied to the owner - such as when you want to have shared ownership: In that case you would want to use a shared pointer.
- You need a compilation firewall to hide implementation details. PIMPL pattern is much simpler to implement using dynamic allocation. A unique pointer is useful here.
- `sizeof` of the sub-object is very big and you want to allocate the owner object in automatic storage. Dynamic allocation is needed here because the memory available to objects in automatic storage is usually limited. Unique pointer is useful here as well - unless the big member is an array, in which case a vector container might be simpler.
- You're implementing a data structure whose size is determined at runtime. Note that standard library provides commonly used data structures for you, and it is quite rare to need to implement custom ones. But if you do, unique pointer is probably going to be useful.

Otherwise, direct members are usually a superior choice.

---

Note that bare owning pointers such as  your `MyClass2::data2` are hardly ever a good idea.

Comment: Sorry but mind if you elaborate more on why having a raw pointer is a bad idea?

Comment: @JeremyHansen because using a bare owning pointer is difficult. There are many traps for beginners and even experiences programmers will occasionally write a bug. For example, if you move assign or move initialise your MyClass2 class, the behaviour of your program will be undefined.

Comment: @JeremyHansen  Please lookup `copy constructor` to find out why your example breaks

Answer (score 0):

Because it is easy to mess up raw pointers and the vast majority of use cases are covered by existing smart pointer types (typical patterns are covered by one of std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr, rarely std::weak_ptr). Note that passing a raw pointer into a function is different in that it should remain stable through the life of the call, if this is not true you need to use something other than a raw pointer anyway.